# Avoid go back page when press return inside field of form react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to avoid, that when i fill a field in my form if i press return key, page go back to the previous page.

I would like that when i press return key, nothing happens or instead go to next field.

this is the code of my form:

Inside a react functional component in the return i have:

```
  <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        render={({ handleSubmit, values }) => (
          <form id='createForm' className="row mt-4" onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
            <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="inputDescription" className="form-label text-center">
                <h5> Título </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-11">
              <Field
                className="form-control"
                type="text"
                name='title'
                component="input"
              // required
              />
            </div>

            <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="inputResponse" className="form-label text-center" >
                <h5> Texto </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-11">
              <Field
                className="form-control"
                type="textarea"
                name='text'
                component="input"
              // required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1 mb-4">
              <label htmlFor="link" className="form-label text-center" >
                <h5> Enlace </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <Field
                className="form-control"
                type="link"
                name="link"
                component="input"
              // required
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-1 mt-1">
              <label htmlFor="link_title" className="form-label text-center" >
                <h5> Título Enlace </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-5">
              <Field
                className="form-control"
                type="text"
                name='link_title'
                component="input"
              // required
              />
            </div>              
            
            
            <div className="buttons text-center mt-2">
              <Volver className={"btn btn-outline-danger me-5 mb-3"} prevStep={prevStep} step={2} />                 
              <button className="btn btn-outline-warning me-5 mb-3" onClick={(e) => (e.preventDefault(), openPreview(values))} >Vista Previa</button>
              <SaveAndEdit className={"btn btn-outline-success me-5 mb-3"} idForm={'createForm'} text={'Guardar Respuesta'} />                  
              <Cancelar className={"btn btn-outline-dark  me-5 mb-3"} />
            </div>               
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form submits, by default, trigger a full page refresh, because this stuff dates back to before AJAX calls or dynamic content were possible.

One simple way to prevent this is to have your `onSubmit` function return `false`, which will prevent this behavior.

Another is to capture the submit event object and call `.preventDefault()` on it.

A third is to not use the form `submit` handler at all. Instead attach yout `onSubmit` function to the click event of the save button.

Remove `onsubmit={handleSubmit}` from this line:

```
<form id='createForm' className="row mt-4" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

...and instead attach it to a click event wherever the user will be clicking to submit the form.  If you were using a plain button this would be:

```
<button onClick={handleSubmit} idForm={'createForm'}>Guardar Respuesta</button>
```

...or you can handle that callback function from within your `SaveAndEdit` component just like any other callback property.

Comment: Yes, i have seen this option and add in my input fields and works perfect:
onKeyDown={(e) => { e.key === 'Enter' && e.preventDefault(); }}

Comment: Hmmmmm.... I wouldn't go that way.  That's the long way around, and you're probably leaving open other ways to accidentally submit the form.  You don't want a true form submit, so just don't use the submit handler.

Comment: i am sure that your solutions works, but i don't know how to implement it. shall you show me some example? thanks

Comment: Expanded the answer with three separate options, any of which should work